# MySQL single query to get the records if any record is active or inactive

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have a scenario where I have 2 tables like below

```
groups

id| name
1 | Group 1
2 | Group 2
3 | Group 3


users

id| name | group_id | sub_status
1 | John | 1        | Active
2 | Doe  | 1        | Inactive
3 | Simon| 2        | Active
4 | David| 3        | Active
```

Now I need to select the groups with active or inactive subscription statuses.
Like if I am looking for `Active` groups, any single I should get Group1, Group2 and Group3 as a result as there is one Active subscription in Group 1. And if I query for `Inactive` groups, I should get `null` because Group1 has one active subscription

Comment: What is the question? Does something not work?

Comment: I think I understand your Specification, but if you show us the expected output based on the input and criteria as a list of rows required it would make it more obvious

Comment: @kerbholz Looking for a query here

Comment: this should produce inactive groups: `select name from groups where id not in (select group_id from users where sub_status='Active');` I don't think this should an answer, tho.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rYwgJypucvqtF23WBrWxeH/0

Answer (score 2):

You can count up active and inactive records by each group. After that, you can filter groups by that count. For example, you can find active groups with the following query

```
SELECT 
 groups.id,
 groups.name,
 sum(IF(users.sub_status = 'Active', 1, 0)) as active_count 
 sum(IF(users.sub_status = 'Inactive', 1, 0)) as inactive_count  
FROM groups
LEFT JOIN users ON users.group_id = group.id
GROUP BY groups.id, groups.name
HAVING active_count > 0
```

and inactive groups:

```
SELECT 
 groups.id,
 groups.name,
 sum(IF(users.sub_status = 'Active', 1, 0)) as active_count 
 sum(IF(users.sub_status = 'Inactive', 1, 0)) as inactive_count  
FROM groups
LEFT JOIN users ON users.group_id = group.id
GROUP BY groups.id, groups.name
HAVING active_count = 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SUM` instead of `COUNT` ?

Comment: @Pepper yes it was the mistake. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to take count? Shouldn't it be enough to just look for  the existence of records that are 'active' (IF EXISTS) or 'inactive' (IF NOT EXISTS)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join the tables.
With EXISTS for active groups:

```
select g.* from groups g
where exists (
  select 1 from users
  where group_id = g.id and sub_status = 'Active'
);
```

and NOT EXISTS for inactive groups:

```
select g.* from groups g
where not exists (
  select 1 from users
  where group_id = g.id and sub_status = 'Active'
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5faf7a0c2e20de432cbfc5b321dd6988).

Comment: this seems a more correct answer. I have deleted mine for the reason you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need such a query :

```
select g.id, 
       case when count(case when u.sub_status = 'Inactive' then 1 end)=1 and 
                 count(case when u.sub_status = 'Active' then 1 end) > 0
            then
         null
       else  
         g.name
       end inactive_case,
       case when count(case when u.sub_status = 'Active' then 1 end) = 1 then
         g.name
       end active_case
  from groups g
  left join users u on u.group_id = g.id
 group by g.id, g.name;

 id inactive_case   active_case
 1                  Group 1
 2  Group 2         Group 2
 3  Group 3         Group 3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9ee7633a9b520a7d61ce6591fb5f57ba)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation for this:

For active groups:

```
select u.group_id
from users u
group by u.group_id
having min(u.sub_status) = 'active';    -- any active member
```

And for inactive:

```
select u.group_id
from users u
group by u.group_id
having min(u.sub_status) = 'inactive';  -- all inactive
```

This uses the fact that `'active' > 'inactive'`.  I would recommend using a 0/1 value instead of a string for this purpose.

Comment: where is field `status` from?